# Jquery 1.7 checkbox and checked

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, checkbox

While I use this

```
 jQuery($("select[id='Input"+id+"OdbcParamsId']")).toggle();
```

and I toggle the select box.
I try to check also after the loading of the page if a checkbox is really checked:
One option:

```
 if($( "checkbox[id='Input_" + id+"Isquery_'").attr('checked', 'checked')){....}
```

Second option :

```
if $( "checkbox[id='Input_" + id+"Isquery_'").is(':checked')) {....}
```

However both do not work. Despite the way I typed it is from fellows on google.
Then the working option for me is :

```
$( "#Input_" + id+"Isquery").is(":checked") {...}
```

And the most bizzare now is that it doesn't fire always the event correctly the following final code of mine:

```
alert($( "#Input_" + id+"Isquery").is(":checked"));
if (!$( "#Input_" + id+"Isquery").is(":checked")){
    jQuery($("select[id='Input"+id+"OdbcParamsId']")).toggle();
}
```

And as you see while the event toggle is really working, the selector no.
I am a very newbie at JQuery, and I don't understand why. Do we have to use different selectors for different events and methods ? Please somebody explain.
Thank you.
**[EDIT]:**
** [HTML CODE] **

```
<td><div class="input checkbox"><input type="hidden" name="data[Input_41][isquery]" id="Input_41Isquery_" value="0"/><input type="checkbox" name="data[Input_41][isquery]"  class="chks" onclick="jqOnOffInputFormDbToggle(41)" options="True False (choose one)" value="1" id="Input_41Isquery"/><label for="Input_41Isquery"></label></div></td>
<td><select name="data[Input][41][odbc_params_id]" id="Input41OdbcParamsId">
<option value="">(choose)</option>
<option value="52">PGSQL1</option>
</select></div></td>
```

I have to say that replacing toggle() with show/hide really works the result.
But the thing with the selector is a bit of awkward mystery for me

Comment: no id for checkbox cause multiple, use name selector

Comment: @khaled_webdev, isn't the id distinct to a form? why use name ?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @jinyuan, when the checkbox is not clicked, hide from screen a select box. but if it is checked, then show it.

Comment: Please mark your edits!  More and more keeps getting added to post and answers are out of synch. HTML would be far more helpful than cake code

Comment: ok ok, I did mark I believe and posted some html

Answer (score 2):

Biggest problem is selector starting with "checkbox" is invalid, there is no tagName "checkbox". There is a jQuery selector ":checkbox", however your first "if" using attr('checked','checked') is not properly set up either.

The last solution is the most efficient anyway since using an ID selector is the most efficient to process, as opposed to $('tagName[attribute="value"]') and it is easier to read

EDIT: more code was added after this was written

Along the lines of my "ID selector is best" , change :

```
   jQuery($("select[id='Input"+id+"OdbcParamsId']")).toggle();
```

To:

```
 jQuery('#Input'+id+'OdbcParamsId').toggle();
```

Use "jQuery" or "$" but mixing them up is causing you confusion, they are the same thing

Comment: Thank you for the proposal, but that would help if hide or show is not working already ( as now it seems it is working but when it wants to ) ?

Comment: without html is hard to say why, are ID's being repeated in page? if so that is a big problem. And get rid of "$()" inside "jQuery".

Comment: I posted the php code, and I replaced the toggle with show/hide functions, so the code really now is working. but the selector part remains a bit of mystery.

Comment: why I used the third option to make it work. It doesn't make sense to me. Why the first two options didn't work ?

Comment: I already explained why they didn't work in my answer...the code was invalid

Answer (score 0):

The toggle says:

```
select[id=Input+id+"OdbcParamsId']"]
```

and the selector says:

```
select["#Input_"+id+"Isquery"]
```

so, is it **Input** or **Input_** ?

Comment: but the toggle is for different control of the form. no relation to each other

Answer (score 0):

First, looks like you have misunderstood how jQuery selectors works, I heavily recommend you to read [the jQuery tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works) **right now**.

Second, your use of `toggle` is not how it's supposed to be used for; maybe it works but it's not the way to do it, in fact `toggle` is an [event binding function](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/).

Now, I assume you're using at least jQuery 1.6, if not maybe the following code doesn't work.

---

To get the value of a checkbox (boolean `true` of `false`):

```js
$("#input_id").prop("checked");
```

To modify a checkbox (marked as checked, change the value to `false` to uncheck it):

```js
$("#input_id").prop("checked", true);
```

To get the value of a select (that is, the value of the selected option):

```js
$("#select_id").find("option:selected").value();
```

To modify the value of a select:

```js
$("#select_id").val("option_value");
```

Here you have a [JsFiddle with some examples](http://jsfiddle.net/pm4MS/4/).

Answer (score 0):

```
if $("#Input_" + id+"Isquery").is(":checked"){
   $("#Input" + id + "OdbcParamsId").toggle();
}
```